# Select all but max(column) with different values for max(column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called document_versions that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `document_versions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `document_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document` text,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to select all but the max(version) of each document in a list of document_id . I can get all entries for a list of document_ids without any problem.  The issue is when I need to put the constraint of "all but max(version)". I've been doing it like this, which obviously doesn't work properly:

```
SELECT * FROM document_versions WHERE document_id IN (SELECT document_id FROM documents WHERE account_id=?) AND version < (SELECT MAX(version) FROM document_versions)
```

Is there a way to apply the document_id constraint inside that second subselect, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document_versions 
WHERE (document_id, id) NOT IN (SELECT document_id, MAX(id)
                            FROM document_versions
                            WHERE account_id = ?
                            GROUP BY document_id)
  AND account_id = ?;
```

Comment: account_id lives in a different table, but this put me on the right path.